# Ultraproduct of pairwise non-equivalent structures

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, filters

It is easy to see that the ultraproduct of a family of structures over a principal ultrafilter is elementarily equivalent to the structure whose index generates the ultrafilter, i.e. if $U$ is generated by $k \in I$, then $\prod_{i \in I} M_i / U \equiv M_k$. My question is, does the inverse also hold? That is, if $\prod_{i \in I} M_i / U \equiv M_k$ does it follow that $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter that focuses on k?

Well, in general the answer is no, because we can simply consider the ultrapower of any structure over a non-principal ultrafilter. Clearly that's gonna be elementarily equivalent to that structure but the ultrafilter can still be non-principal.

Does the same hold if we consider a family of pairwise elementarily inequivalent structures? So, if $M_i, i \in I$ is an infinite family of structures such that $M_i \not\equiv M_j$ for $i\neq j$, does there exist a non-principal ultrafilter $U$ such that $\prod_{i \in I} M_i / U \equiv M_k$ for some $k$, or does $U$ have to necessarily be principal for this to hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can perform the following sort of silly trick. If $M_i$ is a family of pairwise inequivalent structures ranging over an index set $I$ and $U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $I$, write $M_{\infty} = \prod_{i \in I} M_i/U$ for the ultraproduct. There are two cases:

**Case 1:** $M_{\infty}$ is elementary equivalent to some $M_i$. In this case we are done.

**Case 2:** $M_{\infty}$ is not elementary equivalent to any of the $M_i$. Then we can extend $M_i$ to a family of structures ranging over the index set $I_{\infty} = I \cup \{ \infty \}$ which is still pairwise inequivalent. $U$ induces a unique non-principal ultrafilter $U_{\infty}$ on $I_{\infty}$ given by taking all the subsets in $U$ and adding to them all the subsets in $U$ together with $\infty$. Now consider the ultraproduct

$$M_{\infty + 1} = \prod_{i \in I_{\infty}} M_i/U_{\infty}.$$

By Łoś's theorem, $M_{\infty+1} \models \phi$ iff $X_{\infty} = \{ i \in I_{\infty} : M_i \models \phi \} \in U_{\infty}$. By construction, this is true iff $X = \{ i \in I : M_i \models \phi \} \in U$, which is true iff $M_{\infty} \models \phi$ by a second application of Łoś's theorem. So $M_{\infty+1}$ is elementary equivalent to $M_{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This trick is actually quite cool, a lot neater than I was expecting an answer to be. I'm not sure about one direction in the elementary equivalence though. We know that $\prod_{i \in I \cup \{\infty \}} M_i / U_{\infty} \models \phi$ iff $X_{\infty} = \{ i \in I \cup \{\infty\} : M_i \models \phi \} \in U_{\infty}$. From this we have that $X = \{ i \in I : M_i \models \phi \} \in U_{\infty}$. To obtain an elementary equivalence this ought to be in $U$. Does this necessarily hold? Couldn't the extended non-principal ultrafilter we took have introduced this "big" subset?

Comment: @Ioannis: okay, I fixed it. I was being silly about the ultrafilter extension; there's a unique extension (it's the functor part of the ultrafilter functor) and the unique one makes everything work.

Comment: Yeah, I think that does it. I probably thought about it too much. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ioannis: no problem! I am too lazy to check this but I wonder if it's even the case that $M_{\infty+1}$ is isomorphic to $M_{\infty}$, not just elementary equivalent.

Comment: @IoannisEleftheriadis: Another way to see what is happening here: an ultraproduct (with respect to $\mathcal U$) is (trivially!) either isomorphic to $\mathcal U$-almost all the components, or to $\mathcal U$-almost none of them. In the former case, you might as well assume it is equivalent to all of them. In the latter case, you might as well assume that it is equivalent to none of them (although nothing prevents you from adding lots of redundant models into the mix, as long as you don't change the ultrafilter).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: It is isomorphic, via $[(a_i)_{i\in I\cup \{\infty\}}]\mapsto [(a_i)_{i\in I}]$. Generally, changing something on a null set (or even adding more null sets) yields a (canonically) isomorphic ultraproduct.